# SSIS deployed package fails to map drive tag to network shared folder

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Modifying this post as a friend has helped me figure it out.

The culprit was that SQL was not able to map drive tag to network shared folder, so the deployed SSIS package was not able to write. The execution report showed all green and success, so I was confused as a beginner. See also the comments below.

Backup original post below:

SSIS package text file write works in visual studio not when deployed on sql server

I have narrowed down the issue to the text file writing action in script task (C#), the experiment simply writes the current time stamp into a text file.

It works in Visual Studio 2015, both with (F5) and without (Cntl+F5) Debugger. The project is in package deployment mode. When deployed to a database server of SQL Server 2016 and manually trigger execute with Administrator login, the writing action never happens although execution report shows all success, and Windows system log shows no clue to me either.

I am a beginner on SSIS and hints and tips will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should show ur script and flows

Comment: A friend figured out for me, I think we know it now. I used network file sharing and mapped it to drive tag D:\. Visual Studio was able to map D:\ to the network location while SQL server was not able to, and its execution report shows all success despite the error.

Comment: Never use mapped drives. Use UNC instead i.e. `\\server\share\folder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SSIS doesn't like mapping shared folder to a letter drive. Thanks @Nick.McDermaid .

> Never use mapped drives. Use UNC instead i.e. \server\share\folder –
>   Nick.McDermaid Nov 8 '18 at 23:40