# Deployed package execution in SSISDB shows success but write action never happened

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I simplified the issue to a simple write action in C# script task, writing current time stamp into a text file located on the same machine in C:\test\ granted full control to Everyone. The environment is SQL Server 2016, Visual Studio 2015, and Windows Server 2016.

If create a SQL Server Agent job from file system, it updates the text file as expected. If deploy the package into SSISDB and execute, the execution report shows all green and success while the write action never happened. And I was not able to find any clue in system logs.

I will be very grateful to inputs on:
1) What might be wrong in this simple-write test; and
2) How to get more useful log information about this error and possibly other issues.

FYI, Related issues resolved before this post:

[SSIS deployed package fails to map drive tag to network shared folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216239/ssis-deployed-package-fails-to-map-drive-tag-to-network-shared-folder)

Code in the simple-write script task.

```
public void Main()
{
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\test\\simple-write.txt", true, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK"));
            writer.Flush();
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Simple-Write-Test", ex.ToString(), String.Empty, 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your description the SSIS package has executed successfully, so the C# code has executed successfully.  The file 'C:\test\simple-write.txt' is on the same machine the SSIS package is executed on?

Comment: @BobF Yes, it is on the same machine. I used C:\test\ and granted full control to everyone.

Comment: If the SSIS package runs successfully, then the C# code has executed successfully.  Looking at the code would it return "Success" even if it failed?
Have you tried debugging the C# code?

Comment: I slightly changed the test code to catch exception and assign result to ScriptResults.Failure, the test result is still the same. As said before, execute the package in SSISDB context, the execution result shows all green and success, while the write action never happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on the following link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c34874c-03a2-4926-8989-b977c1ec1866/deployed-package-execution-in-ssisdb-shows-success-but-write-action-never-happened?forum=sqlintegrationservices

It seems to be a compatibility issue between the latest version of Management Studio (2017 suite) and SQL Server 2016 database. The script task in the deployed package was silently ignored.